# How to create a keyboard shortcut for inserting time stamp in command history of matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a key board shortcut for inserting time stamp in command history. I follow the standard procedure for creating a keyboard shortcut, however when I press those keys to insert time stamp in command history, nothing happens. Keyboard shortcut is also listed next to the insert time stamp option of command history drop down menu.

Comment: Preferences => MATLAB => Keyboard => Shortcuts, that's where you can set up shortcuts. but I'm not sure you can find the function you want.

Comment: I tried to set up as you mention but when I presses the set keys, nothing happens

Comment: I have checked with Mathworks and they said that if shortcut keys are not setup to any option by default then user cannot set it up.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I use [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/) = Free Text Expander for Windows for this and using the #datetime macro.
Advantage: it works everywhere/ not only in MATLAB ;-)

Comment: I want to create a keyboard shortcut against am existing Matlab functionality. Have you tried in Matlab